# How to insert multiple values in a specific field in a table using mysqli?

Tags: mysql, mysqli

I am working on a project and I I have a scenario like this: I have many field in my table :

```
table_name : transaction_tbl
-id
-name
-description
-ref_number : text(datatype)
```

In my inserting here is my code:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_tbl (`name`,`description`,`ref_number`) VALUES ('$name','$desccription',$ref_number)";

if ($conn->query($sql) === false){
                    trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . 'Error: ' . $conn->error , E_USER_ERROR);
                }else {
                    echo "Successful ! Data is inserted in database ^__^" ;

                }
```

As the name itself ref_number or reference number, so there will be a time that I will have a lot of reference number,how can I let it insert if it will have multiple values? Thanks :)

UPDATES :

I want something like this :

```
name    description            ref_number
bag     to be use               10359435846 
                               05438547656
                               035848576
```

Comment: More importantly, how will you break them apart later?  If that's not a problem, then simply concat() them together in PHP before feeding it to mysqli.

Comment: how can I do that? can you give an example? i am planning to use explode also... is it okay?

Comment: No.  It is really bad form to pack multiple values in a column.  Instead have another table for the "many-to-many" mapping you envision.

Comment: so what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

No.  Don't put multiple values in a column; make a new table:

```
Mapping table
-id -- same as the `id` in transaction_tbl
-ref_number
PRIMARY KEY(id, ref_number)
```

For your example, there will be 3 rows in this table for the 1 row in `transaction_tbl`.

```
INSERT INTO transaction_tbl (name, descripton) VALUES (..., ...)
$id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
INSERT INTO mapping (id, ref_number) VALUE ($id, '10359435846')
INSERT INTO mapping (id, ref_number) VALUE ($id, '05438547656')
INSERT INTO mapping (id, ref_number) VALUE ($id, '035848576')
```

One way of getting the output:

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, t.description,
       GROUP_CONCAT(m.ref_number) AS ref_numbers
    FROM transaction_tbl t
    JOIN mapping m  ON m.id = t.id
    GROUP BY t.id;
```

Comment: what if I Insert only one in my ref_number then multiple values again ,,, and so on ,,, I cannot determine when will I have a multiple values to be inserted or not.. so what should I do

Comment: Where do the ref_numbers come from?  While you are looping through them, `INSERT` each into the table.

Comment: ahm ,,yeah ,,,, by the way thanks :) I just make another table and do the relationship ,,, coz I think if I do not do the normalization there will be a conflict ,, thanks a lot ,,,, u just enlighten my mind :)